# Intuitive meaning of the theorem "Every continuous odd map $f∶S^2⟶\mathbb{R}^2$ has a zero in $S^2.$"

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to get a more intuitive understanding for the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** $ $ Every continuous odd map $f∶S^2⟶\mathbb{R}^2$  has a zero in $S^2.$

Am I right in thinking that this theorem implies that $f$ deforms $S^2$ (through $\mathbb{R}^3$)  onto the closure of a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the origin $(0, 0)$?  So, basically, $f$ is a projection of $S^2$ and its image is always homeomorphic to $D^2$ (the closed unit disc centred at the origin)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem

Comment: @GuiseppeNegro The hairy ball theorem is about vector fields on the sphere. Which locally looks like maps from the sphere to the plane, but they are, ultimately, two quite different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not right. For instance, projecting the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ orthogonally to the $z$-axis is an odd map, and there are plenty of odd maps from the interval $[-1,1]$ on the $z$-axis to the plane. Composing gives you a collection of odd maps from the sphere to the plane. Very few of these give an image homeomorphic to $D^2$, and many of them don't have simply connected images either.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.  Must the image of $f$ be path-connected?

Comment: @Stephen Yes. Any two points in the image comes from two points on the sphere (you may have multiple options; just pick one). There you can path connect them, and then compose that path with $f$ to get a path in the image.